# Change color of Navigation Button SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

How to change the color of Navigation "Back Button" (it's created automatically) to black,
and the color of DisclosureGroup "Chevron" to another color?

[image]

I've tried to do `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` and  `.foregroundColor(.black)`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        
                Text("Go to details ->")
                    .foregroundColor(.purple)
                    .underline()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup("All Details", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(.black)

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.accentColor` for such cases

[image: demo]

```
        DisclosureGroup("All Details", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
            
        }
        .accentColor(.black)
```

ADDED

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        
                Text("Go to details ->")
                    .foregroundColor(.purple)
                    .underline()
            }
        }.accentColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE FOR iOS 16

Xcode is now giving a warning that says .accentColor() will be deprecated in a future version. Use .tint() (and NavigationStack instead of NavigationView) instead, like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        
                Text("Go to details ->")
                    .foregroundColor(.purple)
                    .underline()
            }
        }.tint(.black)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup("All Details", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(.black)

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```